# Nexus 10 - not visible to adb on Windows 7 or Linux

Tags: android, usb

adb doesn't recognize my Nexus 10 on Windows 7. Here's what I've done:

1. Installed the SDK and USB driver from Google. Windows 7 sees the tablet as an 'Android ADB Interface.'
2. Put the tablet in developer mode by clicking on 'About tablet' and clicking the build number seven times
3. Put the tablet in Camera (PTP) mode by going to Storage > USB Computer Connection.
4. Started and restarted the tablet, my computer, and the adb server repeatedly.

None of this helps. When I run 'adb devices,' it gives me an empty list. What else can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your USB debugging mode **on**?

Comment: AIUI, the Nexus 10 doesn't have a USB debugging mode. Instead, click 'About tablet' and click the build number seven times.

Comment: My mistake. I didn't notice the new Developer options setting, so I didn't put the device in USB debugging mode. Sure enough, that does the trick. Thanks.

Comment: You should mark an answer as correct please. For me the main issue was finding out about the "click build # 7 times" (are you kidding me?) and then setting developer mode options.

Comment: I had the same problem on Windows 7.<br/>
This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17186551/2207405

Comment: **JUST CLICKING 7 TIMES IS NOT ENOUGH!!!!** You need actually enable debugging in the developer menu which appears on the top level after you clicked 7 times. Also, if your can see device, but it's always `offline` --> check adb version! (should be 1.0.31 or newer)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I had the same problem on Windows 7.

First make sure the Nexus 10 developer mode and USB debugging is on ( if you dont see developer options, tap on About **Settings -> Tablet -> Build Number** a several time and it should activate developer mode)

Check if your ADB driver is in good shape by going into the Device Manager. If not un-install the ADB device manager and **re-install it by pointing Windows to Android SDK location** (It should pick up the driver automatically).

Once it is installed and still it does not work. Go into **Settings-> Storage ->  USB Computer Connection** and select PTP option. Reconnect tablet to the USB.

Hope it helps!.

Comment: I still have the issue with Nexus 10 driver on Windows 7. Doing all the above installed the driver but when type `adb devices` it doesn't recognize the device. Hence I still can't USB debug on the device.

Comment: +1 and I'll add I had problems because I had an old version of the USB driver. Reinstalling a newer one seemed to help.

Comment: Any idea why it has to be PTP Connection, this works for me but I would like to access storage one device which doesn't work in PTP.

Comment: check if Enable USB debugging is turned on after all the above steps

Comment: It took me a while to find USB Computer Connection. You should add to your answer, that it can be found in the upper right Corner when you click on Storage.

Comment: This worked for me, also. I've had devices where I had to select MTP connection, or none of the MTP / PTP options, but sure enough, selecting PTP (Camera Mode) worked for me. And for those of who you might have difficulty finding this setting, it IS under Settings > Storage, but you have to select the ... menu option in the upper right corner to be able to select the USB Computer Connection option, and change those MTP / PTP settings!

Comment: For me PTP mode also worked, MTP didn't work at all.

Comment: After activating “developer mode”, a reboot of the tablet was needed before I could find settings for USB debug mode.

Answer (score 27):

I had some problems with this as well. I was on win 8.

1. Install the SDK and **USB driver** from Google.  USB driver is available in 'Android SDK Manager' in eclipse.
2. Put the tablet in developer mode by clicking on 'About tablet' and clicking the build number seven times (crazy)
3. Open Windows Device Manager and right click 'Android ADB Interface'
4. Click Properties
5. Driver Tab
6. Update Driver
7. Select 'Browse my computer for driver software' Select the 'sdk' folder under the location you installed your sdk in step 1 (e.g. D:\Dev\Software\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk)

Not sure why windows didn't auto-detect it but it didn't.  Could have been because google doesn't actually 'install' the driver into windows or perhaps it was because I had the HTC USB drivers installed because of my old phone.

Comment: works, i see it, but for some reason I get Failed to install appname.apk on device 'R23D1...': timeout! Launch canceled!

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 8 as well -- note that it may not say "Android ADB Interface", mine just said ADB interface under Device Manager>Portable Devices

Comment: Excellent, solved my problem on Windows 8 after a lot of frustration! Mine was reported as "Android Composite ADB Interface"

Comment: worked for me on Windows 8, one thing I had to 0) uninstall USB drivers and reinstall them before the other steps

Answer (score 9):

I started with the same problem as you, but managed to get my adb connection working on a Fedora 16 system as follows:

1. Inserted `0x18d1` into `adb_usb.ini` (I do not bother with the device ID)
2. Inserted the following extra line into `99-android.rules`. It's not the quite the same as yours but I leave you to experiment.

   ```
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev", OWNER="johnp"
   ```
3. Pressed the `settings->about->version` number 7 times.
4. Rebooted tablet and noticed that a new section is created in settings called "developer options".
5. Enabled USB debugging in `settings->about->developer` options.
6. On Fedora performed `adb kill-server`.
7. On Fedora performed `adb start-server`.
8. On Fedora performed `adb devices`.

I now see a new USB device in the list. When I go to my development environment (Eclipse) I see the device there as well.

Comment: That is works, but is it necessary to edit adb_usb.ini and reboot device? It worked for me on gentoo without the steps. I did not 6-8 also.

Answer (score 4):

For those who are still stuck after following the other good answers, try a different USB port ...plus adb restarts just to make sure. That had me stalled for ages.

Comment: Changing the USB port on my Macbook Air did the trick - crazy! :-)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but I downloaded [the drivers from this application](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2001868) and it started working. I used this same technique on Windows 7 and Windows 8

Comment: This app worked for me 2. SkipSoft.net
http://www.skipsoft.net/?wpdmpro=wpdmpro&download=27
Thanx !!!

Answer (score 2):

Followed these instruction installed the correct ADB-drivers for me on Windows 7 http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Comment: This was the solution tht worked for me, initially failed, so I clicked on properties with tablet on dev mode on, went to driver tab, and clicked on update driver, selected the folder downloaded from the URL and it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with the same problem for a month. I tried other Nexus 10's, other ports, other computers ... everything. I thought I tried other USB cables too, but maybe not enough, as when a friend gave me yet another cable debugging worked.

It turns out the problem for me was that the [EMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference) protection of the PC fires off when Nexus 10 is connected via a bad cable to a bad (front-case) port. It is a big tablet, so my guess is it draws a lot of current, and this combined with a badly shielded cable makes the PC freak out.

So my suggestion to people who couldn't solve the problem in any other way is: get a good USB cable (one where the connectors are bulky - means better shielding), rather than a cheap one.

[image]

On the picture: the red cable is bad, the black one is good.

Have fun,

-Stan

Comment: My problem was also due to the wrong (or possible faulty) USB cable.  Possibly I was using a cable from another device!  Switching to a different cable helped.

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was restart the tablet.

Answer (score 0):

You should have done at least two things to get your device recognized on Linux:

1. specify USB manufacturer and device ID in your hot-plug manager
2. add an entry to ~/.android/adb_usb.ini using USB manuacturer ID

You may find manufacturer and device IDs with 'lsusb' command (that's LSUSB in lower case).

Comment: Thank you, but it's still not working. On Ubuntu 11, I added "18d1:4ee5" to ~/.android/adb_usb.ini and I used the same ID in 99-android.rules:

Comment: Here's my first line of 99-android.rules: SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1:4ee5", SYMLINK+="android_adb", MODE="0666" GROUP="plugdev" Any changes needed?

Comment: @user934904 adb_rules says "# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.", you should not put device ID there, only the manufacturer ID. when you connect your tablet, do you see any activity in `dmesg` ?

Answer (score 0):

As strange as it sounds, try switching the tablet between media device and camera mode.  On the 10 ADB only works for me in camera mode, while on the 7 it only works in media device mode.

Comment: It is more suitable in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different usb port.  Worked for me on windows 8.1 with Nexus5/10.