# Android 5.0 Lollipop - Nexus 10 restarting and USB Debugging not detected?

Tags: android, debugging, usb, application-restart

I installed the new android lollipop 5.0 on my Nexus 10. And it works great!

My system is windows 8.1 pro

One problem though, I'm trying to root the tablet so I can have more access like I had with kitkat. Trying to use the root toolkit to do it, and all the other updates since jelly bean have worked beautifully. The thing is though, I can't even enable usb debugging without it restarting the device. This never happened to me before, so I have no clue why its behaving this way. Toggling the usb debugging option makes it restart...

Just to give you a rundown of how it happens.
1. I go to settings > developer options
2. It starts checked. But by plugging it into my laptop, it doesn't get detected.
3. I unplug the device and tap the checkbox to disable debugging. It restarts. I plug it back in, and guess what? It detects it! Well thats great and all, but I can't root it without the usb debugging option enabled!
4. So I check the box again, usb is enabled, but nothing happens. I uncheck it.  boom. The tablet restarts, and the computer no recognizes it.

Help????

Comment: Have a similiar problem, regardless of USB Debugging disabled/enabled, the device is not showing up on Android Studio. Android 5.0 on a Nexus 10.

Comment: I have the similar problem. It is not detecting in my android studio. All other device is working properly. Got any solution?

Comment: Does this post help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438064/nexus-10-not-visible-to-adb-on-windows-7-or-linux

Comment: This is not actually an answer to your question but can help to the users above. If your device has debuggin activated and is not visible in AndroidStudio/Eclipse, when the device is connected to the USB port, go to the notification bar you will see a USB icon with something like this "connected as multimedia device", click on it and change it as "Camera (PTP)". You should now see your devices in your IDEs.

Comment: Have you installed the google driver from the latest Android SDK? In my installation it can be found under "<User login>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver"

Answer (score 4):

Faced similar issue. Due to some bug you have to change: **"connected as multimedia device" to "Camera (PTP)"** in your android phone.You should now be able to see the device in list.